# Regex not correctly identifying string (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I am using the online regex debugger Regexr (www.regexr.com), which is correctly identifying working and non-working Regex's for me for the most part. However, I am stuck on two specific regex's that Regexr identifies as working correctly, yet they won't work in my implementation. The first I am using to locate PGP keys, specifically the header and the footer. My regex is:

```
[-]{5}[A-Z]{3,5}\sPGP\sMESSAGE[-]{5}[^.]
```

and I am using it to identify:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
```

and

```
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

My other regex that won't work in the actual implementation is for identifying UK passport numbers:

```
\b[0-9]{10}GB[RP][0-9]{7}[UMF]{1}[0-9]{9}\b
```

examples that work in regexr:

```
7086493126GBR6510204M150224602

1234567890GBP1234567F123456712
```

Could someone offer some insight as to why these will not work?

Comment: I don't know if it is intended or not but `----END PGP MESSAGE-----` only has 4 dashes to start

Comment: unintended, and fixed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I always use https://regex101.com/ to test my regular expressions. It explains exactly what your regex is doing and tells you if your string is a match.

Try it out!

If you can't identify the problem with that, the regex probably isn't the issue.

Using regex101, I think this might work better: `^[-]{5}[A-Z]{3,5}\sPGP\sMESSAGE[-]{5}$`

If you read the description on `[^.]` it says "match a single character not present in the list below. The literal character `.`".

Comment: Thank you for the tip, though this seems to provide the same functionality as the site I am already using. This one as well confirmed that my regex's should be working.

Comment: If you're only going to be matching `BEGIN` or `END`, don't bother with that `[A-Z]{3,5}` crap, just use `(BEGIN|END)`, possibly marking it as a non-capturing group if necessary (`(?:BEGIN|END)`). Try to make your expressions as readable as possible, for when you go back to them later, and make them as specific to the circumstances as possible, too. You don't want to match `-----FUBAR PGP MESSAGE-----`. That also means, if you know there will be spaces between the words, don't use `\s`, just use a space, or `\ ` if you really want to.

Comment: I have taken all of the suggestions listed here and messed around with varying combinations of them. I still am having no luck detecting my PGP strings. My current regex: 

    `^[-]{5}(BEGIN|END)\ PGP\ MESSAGE[-]{5}$`

Comment: The regex you provided matches `-----END PGP MESSAGE-----` and `-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----`. The regex doesn't seem to be the issue. Are you certain you are using the correct functions to check for a match? Perhaps the string you are checking isn't really what you expect it to be, or the function you are using doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: I am scanning a text document for many different strings with many different regexs, many of which are already working correctly. I created a second regex `-----`, and it finds four instances, as it should. As soon as I change it to `-----B`, It cannot find anything. This seems so strange to me. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: At this point I would probably suggest posting some of your code in your question. Perhaps there is something in it you're missing. I would also copy/paste a relevant sample from the file you're reading from.

Comment: Oy! I finally figured out what was going on. My only regexs that were not working were those that were searching for capital letters... Turns out I had a lower() function call that I had forgotten about in my main driver.

Comment: No problem. Glad you were able to resolve the issue :).

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is the final part of the regex: `[^.]`

That will match any character that is not a literal period. I don't think that was your intended use for it, and it will definitely cause the regex to not match the beginning and end messages by themselves.

Just to be clear -- while `.` is normally a metacharacter, within `[]` it's just a literal character.

As for the GB passport ids, I'd have to see the string in more context, but the problem is almost definitely with the word boundary metacharacters.

Comment: Thank you, your response makes sense, though after making the changes you recommended I am still not able to detect my PGP strings. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: What are the strings you're trying to detect, and what does the code actually look like?

Comment: I am scanning a text document for many different strings with many different regexs, many of which are already working correctly. I created a second regex -----, and it finds four instances, as it should. As soon as I change it to -----B, It cannot find anything. This seems so strange to me. Do you have any ideas? –

Comment: Sorry, don't know what to tell you without more context -- it works for me. `re.search(r"-{5}(BEGIN|END)\ PGP\ MESSAGE-{5}", "\ns-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----abcdef\n") is not None  # True`